# IE8/9 - javascript:function() as href attribute in secure page (https)

Tags: javascript, html, security, internet-explorer-8, frontend

I have a snippet like this from an external module integrated into our code in a secure page.

```
<a href="javascript:somefun()">Click here </a>
```

This function is not getting executed in IE8/9 whereas it works properly in other browsers. Our testing environment doesn't have valid security certificates. I was wondering if this might be because of some security concerns as the same module works properly in our production. I tried finding some relevant docs but in vain.I was lead to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP but i couldn't find anything comprehensive.

Comment: What happens if you try `onclick="somefun()"` instead of the `href="javascript:somefun()"`?

Comment: It works. But as i said, that is an external plugin and i cannot modify it. So I am trying to figure out what the issue is